# Use single quote in string inspection

Tags: ruby

I have the following program:

```
args = ["a", "b"]
cmd_args = args.map{|x| x.inspect}
str =  cmd_args.join(' ')
puts str
```

The output is:

```
"a" "b"
```

I expect the output to be like the following (sub-string quoted with `'` instead of `"`):

```
'a' 'b'
```

I don't want to do a `gsub` after string `inspect` because, in my real system, substring might contain `"`. For example:

```
args = ['a"c', "b"]
cmd_args = args.map{|x| x.inspect.gsub('"', '\'')}
str =  cmd_args.join(' ')
puts str
```

will output:

```
'a\'c' 'b'
```

The `"` between a and c is wrongly replaced. My expected output is:

```
'a"c' 'b'
```

How can I make string inspect to quote strings with `'` instead of `"`?

Comment: Note that Ruby doesn't make any guarantees about `#inspect` except that it is human-readable debugging output. You should never, ever, parse its output or rely on a specific format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = 'a"c'.inspect
s[0] = s[-1] = "'"
puts s.gsub("\\\"", "\"") #=> 'a"c'
```

Comment: I choose to accept this answer although the other answer from @Jesse Sielaff also works. But this answer is more fit to my needs.

Comment: This fails with: `s = 'a\'c'.inspect; s[0] = s[-1] = "'"; puts s.gsub("\\\"", "\"") #=> 'a'c'` so the answer below would be better suited for consistent quoting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't force `String#inspect` to use a single quote without rewriting or overwriting it.

Instead of `x.inspect`, you could substitute `"'#{x}'"`, but then you would have to make sure you escape any `'` characters that appear in `x`.

Here it is, working:

```
args = ["a", "b"]
cmd_args = args.map{|x| "'#{x}'" }
str =  cmd_args.join(' ')
puts str
```

The output is:

```
'a' 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about correct escaping of `'` via backslash, and consequently of `\` as well, the solutions of both answers will fail. See raimo's comment to sawa's answer. user513951's solution fails in the same way:

```
irb(main):040> x = "b'c"; puts "'#{x}'"
'b'c'
```

Instead, you can use the following function, that properly escapes `'` and `\`:

```rb
  def inspect_str_single_quote(s)
    "'" + s.gsub(/\\/, "\\\\").gsub(/'/, "\\\\'") + "'"
  end
```

If you want to be able to serialize not just plain strings, but arbitrary data structures, potentially containing strings, you may want to roll your own version of `inspect`. Here's a sketch, outlining how it could be done, with TODOs left for the reader:

```rb
  def inspect_single_quote(value)
    case value
    when String
      inspect_str_single_quote( value
    when Array
      "[" + value.map { |item| inspect_str_single_quote(item) }.join(", ") + "]"
    when Hash
      TODO follow "Array" example
    when Set
      TODO follow "Array" example
    when Range # to handle e.g. string ranges
      TODO follow "Array" example
    when Struct
      TODO follow "Array" example
    when OpenStruct
      TODO follow "Array" example
    when Enumerable
      TODO follow "Array" example
    else # fall back to the default inspect, and hope for the best
      value.inspect
    end
  end
```